# WSO2 API Manager: Publish function does not work

Tags: api, wso2, wso2-api-manager

Good afternoon! After I changed the ip address of my wso2 api manager service, I lost the ability to publish new APIs. Error appears: [500]: Internal server error
Error while updating the API in Gateway cdbe7ae3-1aef-4f03-8a3f-f84f530248af
What I did before: I replaced all localhost values ​​with the ip address of the host, I did this in all parameters that are not commented out. First of all, I changed the value of [server]
hostname = "{hostname}", I did all this in the /repository/conf/deployment.toml file.

Please tell me how to solve the problem!

I also independently came to the conclusion that instead of localhost, put the ip address in all parameters in the wso2am-3.2.0 \ repository \ deployment \ server \ synapse-configs \ default \ proxy-services \ WorkflowCallbackService.xml file
After that, I rebooted the server, but it didn't help.

Comment: Do you see any errors in backend? If so, can you update the question with the error log in wso2carbon.log file?

Comment: Surprisingly, if you press the publish button twice in a row, everything works out. The only thing is, the Gateway Environments area is empty.